# Swift 3 - Cannot convert value of type Date? to type 'NSDate' in coercion

Tags: swift3, nsdate, cllocation

I have a global `optional` `CLLocation` variable as follows:

```
var location : CLLocation? = nil
```

I want to unwrap and convert the `timestamp` of the location to `NSDate`.

```
location?.timestamp as NSDate
```

I get the following error

> Cannot convert value of type Date? to type 'NSDate' in coercion.

How do I resolve this?

PS: I am a newbie to Swift 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `location` property is optional and you are trying to get [`timestamp`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocation/1423589-timestamp) from it so that you are getting optional `Date?` instance i.e the reason you are getting that error.

In Swift 3 use `Date` instead of `NSDate` and use `if let` or `guard` to unwrapped optional.

```
if let date = lastSavedLocation?.timestamp {
     print(date)
}
```